# Unable to login to TFS 2010 through jenkins

Tags: tfs, jenkins

Was able to connect to TFS 2008.  After the upgrade to TFS 2010, I am unable to connect.

I reconfigured jenkins to use the new VS2010 tf.exe.

I reconfigured my job to point ot the new URL.
Verified my password is correct...

Within visual studio I can connect and use TFS 2010 without any problems.

However I am getting permissions problesm when trying to use Jenkins.

I have updated to version 1.20 of the TFS plugin and the problem still persists.

I have restarted the service before and after configuration changes...

Any ideas on what might be wrong?  I changed the group/account in the log for safety.

Log is:

```
[workspace] $ "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\tf" workspaces -format:brief -server:http://sbn01p-tfs1001v:8080/tfs ********
TF50309: The following account does not have sufficient permissions to complete the operation: <group>\<my account>. The following permissions are needed to perform this operation: View collection-level information.
FATAL: Executable returned an unexpected result code [100]
ERROR: null
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Jenkins, but it sure looks like it isn't passing the username / password to TFS.

Comment: I'm not sure either but you can see how the account is connecting to TFS by looking in the IIS logs.  It is usually in the 8080 folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Team Foundation Server, beginning with TFS 2010, adds a new concept called Team Project Collections.  Your Team Project Collection needs to be specified in the URI, for example:

```
http://sbn01p-tfs1001v:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection
```